# 8 hex digits out of range for Kotlin Int but works for java int

Tags: java, android, kotlin, unsigned-integer

I'm working on an Android app which gets a color (as a 32-bit number) and I would like to show it using an Android  `Drawable`,

I also want to make sure there's no transparency, so I `OR` it with a mask that has the most significant bits set.

My app is written in Kotlin, so this number is of `Int` type.

in Java, I think the following works

```
int colorInt = myColor || 0xFF000000;
```

I tried the following with Kotlin

```
var colorInt:Int = myColor or 0xFF000000 // Error - Integer literal does not conform to the expected type of Int
```

This complains that `0xFF000000` is out of range for `Int`

I can use a `UInt` for this, but the `Drawable` class and many other SDK methods accept `Int` for colors and complains about types if I pass `UInt`. 
For example, if I have 2 colors I want to use in a `GradientDrawable`, the constructor accepts `IntArray` and will not work with a `UIntArray`. (Also as I understand, unsigned types are experimental in Kotlin, so I prefer not to be going around "fixing" these later after I update the Kotlin version.)

I can use `-0xFFFFFF` in Kotlin and that seem to work fine for this case, though it's arguably not as obvious what I'm doing as the java version.

I would like to understand the best way to proceed for this case, and the reason why this difference exists in java and kotlin.

Comment: can't use UInt and then it's toInt() function to convert the UInt to normal Int???

Comment: wow.. yes it does. thank you 

Answer (score 0):

Since Kotlin 1.3 you can use [unsigned integers ()](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#unsigned-integers) as `Int` is signed (therefore hexadecimal `0xFF000000` is out of range). Now you could try:

```
// UInt instead of Int
// u suffix at the end of number
val m:UInt = 0xFF000000u
```

Comment: I cannot use `UInt`, because SDK methods expect Int. I have used `0xFF000000.toInt()` as the related question. Thanks you.